How to implement singleton such that It collects data from 4 view controllers and submit them with POST API in Swift
I have currently implemented Singleton to collect data and submit it with API CALL
The issue is even after validating null values,the singleton does not updates rapidly and crashes the database record due to insufficient values passed
your text
I tried notification center and tried putting singleton population in viewDidDisappear and Text Did change but it didnt worked

Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: minimal code. Read also how to ask a question
